# Таблица HTML съезжает

Tags: html

У меня есть таблица, столбцы которой почему-то съёзжают. Как сделать так, чтобы надпись была всё время в одном месте?

```css
body {
    font-family: monospace;
}
.block {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    height: 135px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.block_main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
    height: 54px;
}
.stata100 {
    width: 98%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.shkala {
    background-color: blue;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
}
.shkala_red {
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
}
.main {
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.plus {
  color: green;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.minus {
  color: red;
  font-size: 15px;
}
p {
  font-family: normal;
}
summary {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#control {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Hello world!</title>


</head>
<body>
<!-- <p>Вы просматриваете статистику клуба <i>/w/126/56</i>. Статистика обновляется каждые <b>15 минут</b>.</p> -->
<table id='control'>
<tr>
<td>
<section>
<details>
<summary>Основная стастистика:</summary>
<div class="block"><p>Всего участников в клубе:</p><div class="block_main"><span class='main'>76</span><span class='plus' title='За последние 24 часа'>(+8)</span></div><center><div class="stata100"><div class="shkala" title='Максимальное количество людей в клубе: 129' style='width: 78%'><b title='По отношению к масимальному количеству людей в клубе'>78%</b></div></center></div></div>
<div class="block"><p>Максимум участников в клубе:</p><div class="block_main"><span class='main'>129</span></div><span style='font-size: 18px'><i>Это было 2.09.2022</i>.</span></div>
<div class="block"><p>Активных участников в клубе:</p><div class="block_main"><span class='main'>51</span><span class='minus' title='За последние 24 часа'>(-1)</span></div><center><div class="stata100"><div class="shkala" title='Сколько это процентов всех участников клуба' style='width: 66%'><b>66%</b></div></center></div></div>
<div class="block"><p>Забаненных участников в клубе:</p><div class="block_main"><span class='main'>7</span></div><center><div class="stata100"><div class="shkala_red" title='Сколько это процентов всех участников клуба' style='width: 8%'><b>8%</b></div></center></div></div>
</details>
</section>
</td>
<td>
<section>
<details>
<summary>Статистика по сильным игрокам:</summary>
<div class="block"><p>Всего участников в клубе:</p><div class="block_main"><span class='main'>76</span><span class='plus' title='За последние 24 часа'>(+8)</span></div><center><div class="stata100"><div class="shkala" title='Максимальное количество людей в клубе: 129' style='width: 78%'><b title='По отношению к масимальному количеству людей в клубе'>78%</b></div></center></div></div>
<div class="block"><p>Максимум участников в клубе:</p><div class="block_main"><span class='main'>129</span></div><span style='font-size: 18px'><i>Это было 2.09.2022</i>.</span></div>
<div class="block"><p>Активных участников в клубе:</p><div class="block_main"><span class='main'>51</span><span class='minus' title='За последние 24 часа'>(-1)</span></div><center><div class="stata100"><div class="shkala" title='Сколько это процентов всех участников клуба' style='width: 66%'><b>66%</b></div></center></div></div>
<div class="block"><p>Забаненных участников в клубе:</p><div class="block_main"><span class='main'>7</span></div><center><div class="stata100"><div class="shkala_red" title='Сколько это процентов всех участников клуба' style='width: 8%'><b>8%</b></div></center></div></div>
</details>
</section>
</td>
<td>
<section>
<details>
<summary>Статистика по титульным игрокам:</summary>
<div class="block"><p>Всего участников в клубе:</p><div class="block_main"><span class='main'>76</span><span class='plus' title='За последние 24 часа'>(+8)</span></div><center><div class="stata100"><div class="shkala" title='Максимальное количество людей в клубе: 129' style='width: 78%'><b title='По отношению к масимальному количеству людей в клубе'>78%</b></div></center></div></div>
<div class="block"><p>Максимум участников в клубе:</p><div class="block_main"><span class='main'>129</span></div><span style='font-size: 18px'><i>Это было 2.09.2022</i>.</span></div>
<div class="block"><p>Активных участников в клубе:</p><div class="block_main"><span class='main'>51</span><span class='minus' title='За последние 24 часа'>(-1)</span></div><center><div class="stata100"><div class="shkala" title='Сколько это процентов всех участников клуба' style='width: 66%'><b>66%</b></div></center></div></div>
<div class="block"><p>Забаненных участников в клубе:</p><div class="block_main"><span class='main'>7</span></div><center><div class="stata100"><div class="shkala_red" title='Сколько это процентов всех участников клуба' style='width: 8%'><b>8%</b></div></center></div></div>
</details>
</section>
</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что у вас куда сьезжает?

Comment: когда я нажимаю на надпись внутри тега summary, остальные теги summary съезжают вниз

Comment: В `<style>...</style>` добавьте `tr { vertical-align:top; }`

Comment: @TemirStack стало работать, спасибо больше